# Data safety form in google play console does it require a publishing of the app?

Tags: android, google-play-console

As you all know DataSafety is now mandatory when publishing an app.
We do not want to re-publish the app again at this stage.

1. Do you know if it's possible just to update the Data Safety section without publishing the app again ?
2. Does it apply to apps that already exists in playstore or just for new apps ?]

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it applies to all apps in the Play Store; and no, you do not need to resubmit your application. You only need to submit your Data Safety Declaration.

The google play support documentation covers everything you need to know on the [Data Safety](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en) and after personally filling it out, its pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have the documentation 2 3 times but could not find the section where it Said that submitting the app is not required

Comment: All good. The data safety form is separate from the app entirely.  Unless you declare something that is not consistent with your current app, you won’t need to resubmit.